# google api v3 youtube.search.list not displaying any video in channelid

Tags: api, youtube

I am trying to figure out why my url:

https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?part=snippet&channelId=UCUOXu3GcaCPXXU_79wTPy_g&q=webcam&key={YOUR_API_KEY}

worked 2 months ago but is now *not* returning any of my videos in the search. I replaced the api key above obviously but this does not return anything now. I have verified my channelId. Also if I get rid of the channelId it seems to search youtube just fine. Is there some kind of age to my videos that makes them obsolete to the search? Anyone understand why this isn't working.

Comment: Did you find the solution to your problem? I think I have the same issue : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25775090/search-videos-from-a-specific-channel-with-youtube-api-v3

Answer (score 0):

This is an old question and you have probably solved it now, but in case someone needs an answer:

I assume that you are using the Google API package from NuGet? If so, what version are you on. I got the same problem with the latest version. I wound the package back to version 1.14.1.574 and it all works. Annoying, but at least it is all working.

I uninstalled and reinstalled a lot of versions to find the one that worked and .574 was the latest.