# Search videos from a specific channel with Youtube API v3

Tags: ios, youtube, youtube-api

In my project I am trying to make a search query with keywords in a specific Channel. In the documentation of Youtube API v3, they say that to search in a specific channel you need to put the channelId in the query but it doesn't seem to work.

Right now, I'm using the library "YouTube Direct Lite for iOS" https://github.com/youtube/yt-direct-lite-iOS

Does anybody know what is the right way to make a search query like I want with this library or even the URL to make the request?

```
GTLQueryYouTube *queryUpload = [GTLQueryYouTube queryForSearchListWithPart:@"id,snippet"];
queryUpload.channelId = CHANNEL_ID;
queryUpload.q = QUERY;
```

**UPDATE**
The tests work really fine made on the API explorer on the Google Developer Youtube API v3 : (https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer/#p/youtube/v3/youtube.search.list)

BUT when I use the library YouTube Direct Lite for iOS, it returns videos from other channels even if I set the channelId.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

What's the error you are getting? Your query works fine for me.
UPDATE: Please try again, I believe there was an outage on this before.

https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer/#p/youtube/v3/youtube.search.list?part=snippet&channelId=UC3On_d5G5RJRUF8MohJGV_g&q=racing&_h=1&

You can further specify type=video to get only videos as response.

For code sample, you can check: https://github.com/youtube/yt-direct-lite-iOS

Comment: I updated my question with more explanation. It works really fine on the website but with the library, I don't have the same results